Laravel Inertia Vue php artisan breeze:install vue
  npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: vite@4.5.3
npm ERR! node_modules/vite
npm ERR!   dev vite@"^4.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vite@"^5.0.0" from @vitejs/plugin-vue@5.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue
npm ERR!   dev @vitejs/plugin-vue@"^5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!

when running the command php artisan breeze:install vue

Have you tried just php artisan breeze and select inertia vue instead?
